# How to do a parallel cbind

Tags: r, cbind

I have three tibbles a,b,c in a vector `first=c(a,b,c)`. I have another three tibbles in another vector `second=c(d,e,f)`. How do I do a parallel cbind? So a should be cbinded with d, b with e, and c with f. I started out with something like

```
lapply(first,function(item){})
```

but I don't know how to take the second list into consideration in a "parallel" way.

Example-

```
a1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(4,5))
a2<-data.frame(a=c(5,6),b=c(7,8))
a3<-data.frame(e=c(34,26),f=c(41,65))
a4<-data.frame(e=c(13,25),f=c(14,57))
```

I want to cbind a1 to a3, and a2 to a4 to produce

```
  a b  e  f
1 1 4 34 41
2 2 5 26 65
```

and

```
  a b  e  f
1 5 7 13 14
2 6 8 25 57
```

Comment: `Map(cbind, first, second)` ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Assuming each tibble has 2 columns, this cbinds the first column of a with the first column of d, the second column of a with the second column of d, and similarly for b and e, and for c and f. I want a to be cbinded with d, b with e, and c with f.  I don't want to go down to the level of the constituent columns. Please see my edit.

Comment: So `Map(cbind, list(a1, a2), list(a3 ,a4))` ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Works. Thank you. What is the difference?

Comment: I am not exactly sure about the structure of  `first`, `second` but I think it is lists of lists? If you have more than these 4 dataframes and don't want to manually include them in a `list` we can also automate to get all the data in a list, divide them into halves and then `cbind` parallelly.

Comment: And how is that done? If it is not too much trouble, can you enhance your response below? first and second are lists of dataframes, and since a data frame is list, yes, lists of lists.

Comment: I just added that information in another answer. Hope that answers.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Yes, it does. Thank you. Is there one comprehensive reference for all of these commonly used constructs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create list of `a1`, `a2` and `a3`, `a4` and use `Map` to `cbind` them.

```
Map(cbind, list(a1, a2), list(a3 ,a4))

#[[1]]
#  a b  e  f
#1 1 4 34 41
#2 2 5 26 65

#[[2]]
#  a b  e  f
#1 5 7 13 14
#2 6 8 25 57
```

`purrr` equivalent is :

```
purrr::map2(list(a1, a2), list(a3 ,a4), cbind)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we have the character vectors for objects, use `mget` to return the values of the objects in a `list` and then use `map2` to loop over the corresponding `list` elements  and bind the columns with `bind_cols`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(mget(first), mget(second), bind_cols)
```

Comment: Can you suggest a comprehensive reference for all of these special, slightly offbeat constructs? Thank you.

Comment: @user2371765 you meant the `mget` or the tidyverse functions `bind_cols`, `map2` etc

Comment: Both. And, in general, for similar constructs.